# PHP Show links a user haven't clicked

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys I am trying to code this link exchange site where users click other users links to get clicks of their own. What I am trying to accomplish is display a list of links that the user have not clicked and I am stuck!
I managed to display the links but I don't know how to show only the ones they have not clicked.
Every time they click a link their username, the link id and the link name goes into the database.

Help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using MYSQL you need to select all links regardless if they have been clicked or not

```
   SELECT links.id, links.link FROM links WHERE links.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM clickedLinks);
```

Comment: You sir DESERVES The highest of high fives Thank You so much! I could kiss you right now!